# Google Spreadsheet: Concatenate values if UNIQUE ID is equal

Tags: join, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I am using g-sheet and trying to combine the company name in the case of the unique ID in the interval is equal

UNIQUE ID: 1 1 1 2 2 3
COMPANY NAME: A B C Z E K

Expected output:

```
1: A, B, C
2: Z, E
3, K
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(
 {A2:A&":", B2:B&","}, 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where not Col1 starts with ':' 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col1"),,9^9)), ",$", )))
```

[image]